# OBJECT_ID of object in another database - how to find database ID or name/fully qualified object name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, metadata

Example:

```
USE AnotherDB
-- This works - same ID as from other DB
SELECT OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable')
-- This works
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable'))

USE ThisDB
-- This works - same ID as from other DB
SELECT OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable')
-- Gives NULL
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable'))
```

Obviously the metadata functions expect a current database.  The BOL entries typically have language like this for functions like `OBJECT_NAME` etc.:

> The Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Database
>   Engine assumes that object_id is in
>   the context of the current database. A
>   query that references an object_id in
>   another database returns NULL or
>   incorrect results.

The reasons I need to be able to do this:

1. I can't USE the other database from within an SP
2. I can't create a proxy UDF stub (or alter anything) in the other databases or in master (or any other database besides my own) to help me out.

So how can I get the database from `OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable')` when I'm in ThisDB?

My goal is to take a possibly partially qualified name from a configuration table, resolving it in the current context to a fully qualified name, use PARSENAME to get the database name and then dynamic SQL to build a script to be able to get to the meta data tables directly with `database.sys.*` or `USE db; sys.*`

Comment: is it that you have the actual id of some object, say 234521345, and you want to retrieve the name of the id from antoher db.. but you have the names of all dbs?

Comment: I don't really need the ID, but if I use one on the way, that will be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do I understand it correctly that you want the db id of AnotherDB?

```
SELECT *
FROM    master..sysdatabases
WHERE   name = 'AnotherDB'
```

Otherwise, you can USE other db's in dynamic SQL if it helps:

```
DECLARE @SQL    NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @objId  INT

SET @SQL = N'
    USE AnotherDB

    SELECT  @id = OBJECT_ID(''customer'')
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
    ,   N'@id INT OUTPUT'
    ,   @id = @objId OUTPUT

SELECT  @objId
```

OR Execute SP's in other dbs with:

```
EXEC AnotherDB.dbo.ProcedureName 
      @paramX = ...
,     @paramY = ...
```

Comment: Yes, is there a way to get that from an object name (which may or may not be fully qualified - either table, schema.table, or db.schema.table)?

Comment: Right - it comes down to taking a possible partially qualified name, resolving it in the current context and then using PARSENAME to get the database name and then something like what you have dynamically to do the rest of my work.

Answer (score 25):

You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT
   name
FROM
    AnotherDB.sys.objects   --changes context
WHERE
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable')
```

This is what you effectively do with `OBJECT_ID('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable')`

This means that you could rely on dbname.sys.objects and avoid confusion with metadata functions.

Note: the [new Catalog views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365(SQL.90).aspx) are designed to be used and not change from version to version, as per the link. In the old days, it was consider bad practice to use system tables but the stigma still remains.
So, you can safely rely on sys.objects rather that the metadata functions.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [PARSENAME function in TSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) - will allow you to pull out any of the 4-part portions of a fully (or non-fully) qualified name. For the database in your example:

```
select parsename('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable',3)
```

returns:

AnotherDB

```
select parsename('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable',2)
```

returns:

ASchema

If non-fully qualified, you'll get null results if you ask for the portion of a name that isn't included in the string:

```
select parsename('ASchema.ATable',3)
```

returns:

*NULL*

Comment: This would be great if I could resolve a partially qualified name to a fully qualified name.  You know how to do that?

Comment: Nope, not possible with native functionality - really no way of doing that aside from checking every database on the instance for an object matching the given non-qualified name, but then how do you handle possible collisions? You could easily create a procedure that would iterate through all of the databases on the system looking for an object matching the given schema/name (leveraging the sp_MSforeachdb system procedure perhaps, or just a cursor through sys.databases) - is that what you want? i.e. return all the databases that have an object matching the given schema/name if no db qualified?

Comment: Actually it's pretty simple    isnull(parsename('unqualified',3),DB_NAME())   .  This obviously assumes that unqualified names should resolve to the current DB but that is not a stretch since it's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but with OJBECT_SCHEMA_NAME as well. Following on from chadhoc's response using parsename works with OBJECT_NAME like:

```
DECLARE @OrigTableName NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @OrigTableName = 'AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable'

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@OrigTableName), DB_ID(PARSENAME(@OrigTableName, 3)))
, OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@OrigTableName), DB_ID(PARSENAME(@OrigTableName, 3)))
```

Comment: This is pointless if you already have the Fully-Qualifed Name.  Just use `ParseName()` **_once_** as @ChadHoc did.  `SELECT PARSENAME('AnotherDB.ASchema.ATable', 1)` will return `ATable`.  This is way better and clearer than the overhead of calling 4 Functions (`Object_Name`, `Object_ID`, `DB_ID`, and `ParseName`) for the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following solution:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(255) = 'SchemaName'
DECLARE @ObjectName varchar(255) = 'ObjectName'

SELECT     o.*
FROM       AnotherDB.sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN AnotherDB.sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE      s.name = @SchemaName
AND        o.name = @ObjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS (

```
    SELECT si.name
    FROM <DatabaseName>.sys.indexes si
    INNER JOIN <DatabaseName>.sys.objects so
    ON si.object_id = so.object_id
    WHERE si.name = '<IndexName>'
    AND so.name = '<TableName>'
```

)
BEGIN

```
    CREATE INDEX [<IndexName>] ON [<DatabaseName>].[<Schema>].[<TableName>] 
    ([column1]) 
    INCLUDE ([<column2>],,,,
    )
    WITH (online = ON)
```

END