# How to get the actual script of a stored procedure in another server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I use SQL Server 2017. I have linked a server\database to another my main database. So, if I execute the query below, it works and brings me the correct data:

```
use [myMainServer].[myMainDatabase] GO

...
Select * from [myOtherServer].[myOtherDatabase].dbo.[myTable]
```

What I want to do is to get the actual script of a stored procedure from the linked database. Assume I have the stored procedure: **sp_GetNumbers**, then I can receive its content if I execute the code below in the linked server itself:

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('sp_GetNumbers'))
```

However I couldn't manage to do it from my main database. I've tried below but does not work.

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID('[myOtherServer].[myOtherDatabase].sp_GetNumbers'))
```

**My question is:** How can I get the script of a Stored Procedure in SQL server B `([myOtherServer].[myOtherDatabase])` by running a query in SQL server A `([myMainServer].[myMainDatabase])`?

Comment: check out the second answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843121/object-id-of-object-in-another-database-how-to-find-database-id-or-name-fully) thread. Obviously, using OBJECT_DEFINITION results in a search among the object definitions of the current database.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the warning, I'll renamed my sp accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object functions are context specific so that won't work, but you could use the system views. Something like this:

```
SELECT [definition] 
from [myOtherServer].[myOtherDatabase].sys.sql_modules m 
inner join [myOtherServer].[myOtherDatabase].sys.objects o
on m.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
where o.[name] = 'sp_GetNumbers'
```